# Multiple choice question Real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

[image]

Answer is given as option d.
As per the definition of the function the function is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.But I want to know why the function is not analytic.How we know it is not analytic?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: If it was analytic at $x=0$, then all the Taylor coefficients would have to be zero (since $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$). But then $f(x)$ would be zero in a neighborhood of $x=0$, which is not true.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: You've been around for a while, certainly long enough to have picked the basic $\LaTeX$ skills needed to post this Question without resorting to an image.  I'm voting to close, but if you edit it to use `MathJax` instead of the image, I'll vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compute all derivatives at $x=0$, you will notice that they are all $=0$. An anylytic function with these derivatives would equal the corresponding power series in a neighbourhood of $0$, i.e., would be constantly $=0$ in that neighbourhood.